# How to mount a pull-up bar to drywall on resilient channels?

Tags: drywall, mounting, studs

I'm trying to mount a pull up bar on a drywall. The wall is shared with another unit though,so there are resilient channels behind the wall, and so the studs are offset from the dry wall sheet. What's the best way to securely mount things into the studs without breaking the dry wall?

Comment: Sounds like a free-standing, or semi-free-standing, solution would be better. Or the classic doorway bar, though many folks may be too tall for that approach these days. (I have that setup, but have to admit I mostly use it as a place to temporarily hang laundry while sorting... and I'm safely under 6' so I can leave it at a usable height and still not hit my head on it.)

Answer (score 2):

There is not a good easy way to structurally mount a pullup bar to a wall with gypsum board on resilient channels which does not significantly impact the existing gypsum board finish because the resilient channels allow for some movement.

Answer (score 1):

It may be better to mount from ceiling joists if at all possible, or else use a free-standing solution as suggested by Keshlam's comment. RC mounting on walls is meant to be flexible enough to absorb vibration, so mounting to those walls would either nullify the purpose of having RC mounted walls, or damage the drywall by exceeding it's structural capacity.